# ChaiScript troubles

Tags: c++, qt, chaiscript

I'm using script language ChaiScript with c++ and Qt. I've defined such function:

```
void ChaiPainter::drawRectangle(QPainter *painter, int x, int y, int height, int width)
{
    painter.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
}
```

And in application paint-event:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    chaiPainter->mChai.add(chaiscript::var(&painter), "painter");
    chaiPainter->mChai.add(chaiscript::fun(&ChaiPainter::drawRectangle), "drawRect");

    chaiPainter->mChai("drawRect(painter, 5, 5, 100, 100)");
}
```

The error is:

> 'chaiscript::Eval_Error'   what(): 
>   Error: "No matching function to
>   dispatch to with function 'drawRect'"
>   during evaluation at (1, 1)

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation it looks like you need to use the `fun(mem_fn, instance)` form to get pre-bound functions:

```
chaiPainter->mChai.add(
    chaiscript::fun(&ChaiPainter::drawRectangle, chaiPainter), "drawRect");
```

Comment: I can't understand, how I missed that. Thank you.